# Replace "#" in query string without changing the actual value

Tags: jsp

I have one query string in my JSP:

```
href='www.me-me.com/index.jsp?application=<%=
  myBean.getApplication().replace("&","\\")
%>&appId=<%=
  myBean.getAppId()
%>'>LINK
```

Now I am picking up the `appID` using request object in the `index.jsp` and using that `appId` I am pulling up the data from my DB to fill the page.

But I am getting a blank screen when `myBean.getApplication` is returning something like `Application ##1`, certainly because query is getting banged after encountering the `"#"`.

I could replace `"#"` using the `replace()` method, but I do not find it reliable and good, as I am pulling that application name using the request object again in my `index.jsp` page, and the replacement of hashes would make it ugly. So is there a way where I can retain the `"#"`?

Any other out-of-the-box solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL-encoding the values would be the right thing to do.

```
href='www.me-me.com/index.jsp?application=<%=
  URLEncoder.encode(myBean.getApplication(), "UTF-8")
%>&appId=<%=
  URLEncoder.encode(myBean.getAppId(), "UTF-8") 
%>'>LINK
```

You can transport any string value as an URL parameter, but you *must* properly encode it or your URLs will break, just like you are experiencing it.

You'd need a

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
```

statement in your page, because that's where `URLEncoder` is defined.

Comment: After encoding the values, I wud need to decode them (URLDecoder.decode) while storing it to request object???

Answer (score 3):

Use [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:url`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) with [`c:param`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/param.html).

```
<c:url var="url" value="http://www.me-me.com/index.jsp">
    <c:param name="application" value="${myBean.application}" />
    <c:param name="appId" value="${myBean.appId}" />
</c:url>

<a href="${url}">LINK</a>
```

No need to hassle with old fashioned *scriptlets*.